# Load UTF-8 encoded HTML site with PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I crawl some informations from a website. Therefore I create a new DOM document and load the website with `loadHTMLFile`.
Now I´ve the problem that the website which I'm crawling uses apostrophes/ french accents. I´ve read that `loadHTMLFile` doesn´t use UTF-8 encoding by default.

So I´ve tried to add UTF-8 encoding manually, but it doesn´t work. The apostrophes still doesn´t show correctly.

For example the letter `ì` (with apostrophe) is shown as `%C3%AC`. Word without apostrophes are shown correctly.

**This is the complete code:**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

foreach (range(0, 50) as $number) {

$url = 'https://www.xxyyy.com/' . $number . '';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTMLFile(mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$dom->substituteEntities = true;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$content = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'character')]/@href");

    foreach ($content as $node) {

      echo $node->nodeValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't UTF-8 at all. Every URL in HTML should be URL encoded. When you fetch the value of `<a href>` you fetch the URL in its encoded form. You must decode the URL to its string form if you want to see the unicode characters. Use [`urldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
echo urldecode($node->nodeValue);
```